# Why using PubNub with Firebase for realtime instead of only Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, pubnub

I am building an android app which uses realtime data provided to users of that app. PubNub is recommended as the world's best servie provider for that. But it requires to use a part of Firebase services as well. Why is that necessary, or rather, why not avoid PubNub and just use the full Firebase realtime service, which should be absolutely capable for that from my understanding?

Comment: This question will probably get flagged because it is not a specific technical question. But basically, you do not need to use Firebase with PubNub. Firebase is many things: FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) is Android Mobile Push Notifications  which is the same thing as APNS on iOS. This is not bi-directional realtime messaging. It is just mobile push notifications. PubNub has a Mobile Push Gateway that allows you to send a mobile push notification to Android and iOS devices when the app is not active (running in the foreground) and therefore is not connected.

Comment: ... continuing from above comment - Firebase is also a realtime database (my shortened description) which is a bit different than PubNub which is a globably distributed, realtime messaging service (which has a Storage component to it). If you need to send/receive messages in realtime (< 1/4s) to/from devices (1 to 1 or 1 to millions), then PubNub is what you need. Firebase has a different primary set of use cases and there is some overlap but I think you will discover the difference once you dive in. You can use both if you want the best of both products. Full disclosure, I work for PubNub.

Comment: By the way, if you have any questions about using PubNub, with or without Firebase and/or FCM, feel free to contact [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com).

Comment: See this Stack Overflow post. It might be insightful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166306/why-firebase-is-needed-for-android-notifications-along-with-third-party-notifica